# I am getting a error Java.lang string cannot be converted to student?

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have a method file name student in which they are a bunch of methods. I need those methods to complete lab 13. I also have a arraylist of student objects. In my lab 13 code i am getting an error that i cannot convert string into Student.

I have tried everything I can forexample i tried to convert it by putting student in the front of the code forexample student.jessica.addfriend("emily"). but it still doesnt work. Please help me wiht my problem.

Thats the code for lab 13

```
   import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Lab13
 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Student jessica = new Student("Jessica", 23, 
 Student.SocialYear.SENIOR);
    Student henry = new Student("Henry", 16, Student.SocialYear.FRESHMAN);

    String n = jessica.getName();
    System.out.println("One student is " + n + ".");

    System.out.println("This student is " + jessica.getAge() + " years old.");

    System.out.print(henry.getName() + " used to be " + henry.getAge() + " years old.");
    henry.getAge();
    System.out.println(" He just had a birthday and is now " + henry.getAge() + " years old.");

    System.out.println(jessica.getName() + " is a " + jessica.getSocialYear() + ".");

    printVote(jessica);
    printVote(henry);

    // HELP! Modify me to use the updated Student class.
    //What type input parameter should be passed into the method?

    jessica.addFriend("Erin");
    jessica.addFriend("Bert");

    henry.addFriend("Isaac");
    henry.addFriend("Kaley");

    // HELP! Modify me to use the updated Student class.
    //       What type of objects does the ArrayList of friends have?
    printFriend(jessica, "Bert");
    printFriend(henry, "Sam");

    // HELP! Create more instances of the Student class for testing.


    // HELP! Add friends to the ArrayLists of the instances.


    // HELP! Print out the favorite friend of one of the students.


    // HELP! Change the favorite friend of one of the students.
    //       The new favorite should already be a friend of the student.
    //       Print out this new favorite friend.


    // HELP! Print out all the friends of one of the students.


    // HELP! Check to see if a student is friends with another student.
    //       This test should be true (the student should have the friend).


    // HELP! Check to see if a student is friends with another student.
    //       This test should be false (the student should NOT have the friend).


    // HELP! A friend transfers and a student loses track.
    //       The student should unfriend the friend.
    //       Print out the updated list of friends.


}

/**
 * This method prints whether a student can vote based on age.
 * 
 * @param s     A Student object
 */
public static void printVote(Student s)
{
    if (s.canVote()) {
        System.out.println(s.getName() + " can vote.");
    } else {
        System.out.println(s.getName() + " is not old enough to vote.");
    }
}

/**
 * This method prints whether a student knows the friend.
 * 
 * @param s     A Student object
 * @param f     A String representing the friend
 */
public static void printFriend(Student s, String f)
{
    if (s.hasFriend(f)) {
        System.out.println(s.getName() + " is friends with " + f + ".");
    } else {
        System.out.println(s.getName() + " does not know " + f + ".");
    }
}
```

}

This is my student method

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Collections;

public class Student
{
public enum SocialYear { FRESHMAN, SOPHOMORE, JUNIOR, SENIOR }

private String name;
private ArrayList<Student> friends;
private int age;
private SocialYear year;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Student
 */
public Student(String n, int a, SocialYear sy)
{
    this.name = n;
    this.age = a;
    this.year = sy;
    this.friends = new ArrayList<Student>();
}

public String getName()
{
    return this.name;
}

public int getAge()
{
    return this.age;
}

public void setAge()
{
    this.age++;
}

public SocialYear getSocialYear()
{
    return this.year;
}

public boolean canVote()
{
    return this.age >= 18;
}

public void addFriend(Student friend)
{
    friends.add(friend);
}

public boolean hasFriend(String friend)
{
    return friends.contains(friend);
}

public void unFriend(Student friend)
{
    friends.remove(friend);
}

public void getFriends()
{
    for(Student s : friends)
    {
        System.out.println(s + ",");
}
}

public Student getFavFriendName()
{  
    return friends.get(0);
}

public void myNewFavFriend(Student friend)
{
    friends.remove(friend);
    friends.add(0, friend);

}    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `addFriend` takes a `Student` as an argument

```
public void addFriend(Student friend)
```

Your code is providing a String.

```
jessica.addFriend("Erin");
```

This would work

```
jessica.addFriend(henry);
```

as you have already created a `Student` called henry.

```
Student henry = new Student("Henry", 16, Student.SocialYear.FRESHMAN);
```

Comment: so what should i do how can i convert it to student

Comment: ohhhhh i c what you mean